# Usage of permissive BSD license

Tags: licensing, bsd, permissive

I want to start one e-commerce site , for which i chose the backbone framework which is under **permissive BSD license** , can i use it for commercial purpose. what are the things do i need to keep in mind. Do i require any permission from author. Or what are the requirements to use that framework in my code base.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. No you don't need permissions. The license text is pretty clear to this effect.